# Cant catch errors when editing

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I'm kinda new to c# and winforms and need some help.

I've created a `dataset` and insert it 2 tables "**order_lines**" and "**products**". i have a `datagridview` with columns taken from the table "**order_lines**"  which is an empty table (with no data) .

So in the `datagridview` i have 3 empty columns: `quantity`, `product` *(which is a `combobox` taken from the other data set table `products`)* and a column `total` which I've created myself *(all other columns such as `product_id` and `order_num` are invisible)*.

I'm trying to allow the user to edit and insert data in the `datagridview` to the columns quantity *(insert number)* to the column product *(choose product from combobox)* and the total should be a calculation of the `quantity*product_price` *(according to the product selected from the combobox each product have an id and the price should be taken from the table `products`  according to the product `id`)*

I have 2 problems:

1. I'm trying to check the user inserted data with the `cell_validating` event and the `data_error`
   but it doesnt work and instead of getting my error message when the user put invalid data i get an the exception `"object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types"` which i dont understand why
2. I don't seem to manage to take the price from the `dataset` table `products` and use it in the total column according to the product selected (in the datagridview which show the dataset table "**order_lines**" theres a hidden column "product_id" also in the dataset table "**products**" i have the column "product_id" and "product_name" which is the combobox in the datagridview) when a user choose a product i need to get the price.

I hope i managed to explain my question, any ideas will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is how I suggest you to do it:

```
DataTable products;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // handle cell changes
    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;

    // used for manually raising the ComboBox change
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
}

void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // return if the row or column headers were changed
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != dataGridView1.Columns["total"].Index)
    {
        var value = 0;

        // get the product id from the ComboBox
        var product = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Product"].Index].Value;

        // get the quantity
        var quantity = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["TotalQuantity"].Index].Value.ToString();

        if (product != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity))
        {
            value =
                int.Parse(quantity) *
                int.Parse(products.Select("product_id = " + product.ToString())[0]["product_price"].ToString());

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["total"].Index].Value = value;
            dataGridView1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```